# how to escape this so it runs of ssh exec

Tags: bash

I have the following bash which works

```
export READ=$(cat /opt/TOKEN.txt);echo "initial_token: $READ" >> cassandra.yaml
```

I need to escape this so it runs over ssh properly so I tried the following

```
ssh host 'export READ=\$(cat /opt/TOKEN.txt);echo \"initial_token: \$READ\" >> cassandra.yaml'
```

yields error

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `export READ=\$(cat /opt/TOKEN.txt);echo \"initial_token: \$READ\" >> cassandra.yaml'
```

as well as

```
ssh host 'export READ=\$\(cat /opt/TOKEN.txt\);echo \"initial_token: \$READ\" >> cassandra.yaml'
```

yields error

```
bash: line 0: export: `/opt/TOKEN.txt)': not a valid identifier
```

Anyone know how to escape this?
thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are escaping too much – bash already does no interpretation of single-quoted strings:

```
ssh host 'READ=$(< /opt/TOKEN.txt); echo "initial_token: $READ" >> cassandra.yaml'
```

Answer (score 2):

ah man, this is waaaaaayyyyy cool.  I just found this so I don't need to worry about escaping ANYHTHING...

```
ssh user@serverB <<\EOF
your sql query....
.....
.....
EOF
```